# How to resize bitmap image programmatically with out missing the data

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an android application in which i want to set a Banner image on top of the screen which will come from server, i need to resize it dynamically according to the device size programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

int iWidth=bmp.getWidth();
        int iHeight=bmp.getHeight();

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(dm);

    int dWidth=dm.widthPixels;
    int dHeight=dm.heightPixels;

    float sWidth=((float) dWidth)/iWidth;
    float sHeight=((float) dHeight)/iHeight;

    if(sWidth>sHeight) sWidth=sHeight;
    else sHeight=sWidth;

    Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(sWidth,sHeight);
    newImage=Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, iWidth, iHeight, matrix, true);
    imageview.setImageBitmap(newImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to set an ImageView declared in your layout (for example with properties `android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"`) you can adapt the following code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;  // just compute size, don't create bitmap
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, options); // stream is the InputStream representing the image you want to display
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
imageViewWidth = imageView.getWidth(); // imageView is the View container for the image you want to display
imageViewHeight = imageView.getHeight();
// Compute the sample size
double sampleSize = computePowerOfTwoInSampleSize(options, imageViewWidth, imageViewHeight);
if(sampleSize<1) { 
    options.inSampleSize = 1; 
}
else { 
    options.inSampleSize = (int) sampleSize; 
}
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false; // compute size and create bitmap  
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, options);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
try { 
    stream.close(); 
} 
catch (IOException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

where the method `computePowerOfTwoInSampleSize` is something like this (take into consideration that resizing to power of 2 is more efficient compared to other values):

```
private double computePowerOfTwoInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    int height = options.outHeight;
    int width = options.outWidth;
    double inSampleSize = 1;        
    // compute the up-sample coefficient (power of 2)
    if(height < reqHeight && width < reqWidth) {
        while(height < reqHeight && width < reqWidth) {
            height = height*2;
            width = width*2;
            if(height < reqHeight && width < reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize = inSampleSize/2;
            }
        }
    }
    // compute the down-sample coefficient
    else {
        while(height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) { 
            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width (power of 2)
            height = Math.round((float)height/2);
            width = Math.round((float)width/2); 
            inSampleSize = inSampleSize*2;
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check out the `scale` attributes of the ImageView in xml first

And resize using this

```
public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image)
{
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, x, y, true);
}
```